# Fullcalendar V5 - Filter from form

Tags: javascript, forms, filter, fullcalendar

i just update fullcalendar V3 to V5 and have some issues.

Before i use eventRender like this, with #team_selector and #task_type_seletor classes from a form.

```js
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
          const team = event.team.toString();
                    console.log(team);
                    const selectedValues = $('#team_selector').val();

          const type_event = event.className.toString();
                    console.log(type_event);
                    const selectedValues2 = $('#type_event_selector').val();

                    return (selectedValues.includes('all') || selectedValues.includes(team)) && (selectedValues2.includes('all') || selectedValues2.includes(type_event));
                    
                    },
```

```js
$('#team_selector').on('change',function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});

$('#type_event_selector').on('change',function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});
```

Bur now, how i'am supposed to use #team_selector and #task_type_seletor with fullcalendar v5, because EventRender doesn't exist anymore.

Thank you !

Comment: Best to reach out to the supporter of this product.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks . I'd suggest using the class name hook to decide whether to add a class to the element which would hide it